# Does the Bonferroni Correction apply across metrics/KPIs?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, bonferroni, ab-test

Say I am running an A/B test with three total variants and two treatments (Control, T1, and T2). I am also calculating multiple KPIs--say two KPIs (K1 and K2)--for this test.

> If I apply the correction to the number of treatments, then I would divide my significance level by n = 2 (T1,T2).

> If I apply the correction to the number of treatments (T1,T2) **and** KPIs (K1,K2), then I would divide by n = 2x2 = 4.

So which is the correct application? Is it based upon the number of treatments? Or the number of treatments and KPIs?

Comment: Make a list of every non-null hypothesis that you are testing - e.g. "KP1 is higher under T1 than T2", "T2 increases KP2 more than it increases KP1", etc. The number of hypotheses in the list is the correction factor. (Or you could just not use the Bonferroni correction at all - the point of it is to bound the familywise error rate, and it's up to you whether you care about that.)